# The solutions of Linear Algebra by Peter Petersen.

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

I'm reading Linear Algebra by Peter Petersen recently, and want to try the exercises in the textbook. However, I cannot find the solution manual of the textbook, which makes me have a lot of troubles in making sure whether my solutions to the exercises are correct. So, has anybody know whether there is a solution manual of this textbook, and provide some clues for me to find it?

Thanks very much.

Comment: For reference, [here](http://www.calpoly.edu/~jborzell/Courses/Year%2010-11/Fall%202010/Petersen-Linear_Algebra-Math_306.pdf) is a pdf of the textbook.

Comment: Well, thanks very much. But in fact, I have had the textbook. What I really need is the solution manual of the textbook. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to make your own solutions (I think there are no solutions around, just google it). This is the best way to actually learn the subject: Ask people who now the subject about your solutions and try to improve them, because then you fully understand what you are doing. If you do not want to go through it like this, then you have to choose another book, or try an exercise book or see on university pages for exercise sheets with solutions.

Comment: In fact, I am trying to go through them now, but without the solution manual, I am not that sure whether my answers are correct. I have googled and asked people, but sometimes, you may make mistakes at where you are confident you are right and won't ask for the correct answers unless you really have the correct answers at hand. That's the reason why I want to find  a solution manual. Anyway, thanks very much for you suggestion.

Comment: That is the right way of doing it. But unfortunately, there is no solution manual to this book. Most of the books published do in fact not have any solutions.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like that. So I try to get some clues here. Now, I can give up looking for the solution manual. Thanks very much.